# iOS forward geocoding not being executed

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, geocoding, core-location

Can anyone tell me why this block of code isn't being executed? I copied and pasted it from another project of mine, where it works just fine. I also tried it in my other app with the same addressString I'm plugging in here, and it worked perfectly. but it happens oly while passing string variable if I pass the address directly to geocodeaddressstring it works fine

```
NSString *addressString = @"2642 Broadway, New York, NY 10025, USA";
[forwardGeocoder1 geocodeAddressString:addressString
                          completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error){

                              // Make sure the geocoder did not produce an error
                              // before continuing
                              if(!error){

                                  // Iterate through all of the placemarks returned
                                  // and output them to the console
                                  for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks){

                                NSLog(@"found");

                                  }
                              }
                              else{
                                  // Our geocoder had an error, output a message
                                  // to the console
                                  NSLog(@"There was a forward geocoding error\n%@",
                                        [error localizedDescription]);
                              }
                          }
       ];
```

error:
kCLErrorDomain error 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010237-CH2-SW2)

According to the documentation, `kCLErrorDomain error 8` means: `kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult`

Comment: if i pass address like this NSString *addressString = [addressArray objectatindex:0];
then only am getting the above error

Comment: @Arvind, please paste your complete code. It will help understanding the situation.